# removing array elements by indexes from an array ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I have an array of words like so

```
["jo","jibber","hail","noobs","smirk","awkland"]
```

and a seperate array with indexes

```
[0,3,5]
```

I want to remove all the elements from the previous array at those indexes.
I was thinking i could use reject but im not sure exactly how i would do it. Also once i remove one element wont all the other indexes would have to change.
Is there an easy way of doing this??

Comment: You could also use delete_at but Sergio Tulentsev answer is great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`reject`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject) and `with_index`

```
arr = ["jo", "jibber", "hail", "noobs", "smirk", "awkland"] 

indexes = [0, 3, 5]

arr.reject.with_index {|_, idx| indexes.include?(idx)} # => ["jibber", "hail", "smirk"]
```